# using jquery to hide and show buttons on option change on the dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to display different buttons on selecting different field from the drop down. here's my code, it's working partialy only for the first item in the dropdown. Please advice what's wrong with my code:

```
<select id="my_id">
  <option value="select">--Select--</option>
  <option value="foo">foo</option>
  <option value="bear">bear</option>
</select>

<div id="display_bt1" style="display:none;">
  <input type="button" value="bt1" onclick ="" > 
</div>
<div id="display_bt2" style="display:none;">
  <input type="button" value="bt2" onclick ="" >
```

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#my_id').change(function() {
      if ($(this).val() == 'foo') {
         $('#display_bt2').show();
      } else if ($(this).val() == 'bear'){
         $('#display_bt1').show();
      } else {

      }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Missing a ' on `$('#display_bt2')`

Comment: Yep and not sure if you are looking for value 'bear' or 'bar', but assume the latter, which means the spelling is incorrect.

Comment: Close [all] the typos.

Comment: Showing the select markup would clarify the values.

Answer (score 3):

Some syntax errors, other than that, it should work:

```
$('#my_id').change(function() {
    if (this.value == 'foo') {
        $('#display_bt2').show();
    } else if (this.value == 'bear') {
        $('#display_bt1').show();
    }
});
```

If you want to hide the other div on the `change`, add a class to each div, for example `divClass`, then hide that class on each change (of course this is if you want this functionality).

```
$('#my_id').change(function() {
    $(".divClass").hide();
    if (this.value == 'foo') {
        $('#display_bt2').show();
    } else if (this.value == 'bear') {
        $('#display_bt1').show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks tymeJV for your response. sorry, I didn't what you mean by add class to each div. Do you suggest to wrap <div id="display_bt1" style="display:none;">
  <input type="button" value="bt1" onclick ="" > 
</div> around a div class?

Comment: this.value is not working at all, where as my previous $(this) works for me.

Comment: Mind posting your HTML markup for your select list? I can give a better answer then.

Comment: here you go:<select id="my_id">
   <option value="select">--Select--</option>
   <option value="foo">foo</option>
   <option value="bear">bear</option>
 </select>

Answer (score 0):

You can add `name` attribute to input element

```
<select id="my_id">
    <option>foo</option>
    <option>bear</option>
</select>

<div id="display_bt1" style="display:none;">
    <input type="button" value="bt1" name="foo" onclick ="" /> 
</div>
<div id="display_bt2" style="display:none;">
    <input type="button" value="bt2" name="bear" onclick ="" /> 
</div>
```

And then you can itterate over array of elements and compare selected option value with input's parent name attribute like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#my_id').change(function() {
        $this = $(this);
        $('#display_bt1, #display_bt2').each(function() {
            $(this).hide();
            if($this.val() == $(this).children().attr('name')) $(this).show();
        });
    });
});
```

It's maybe not best way how to do it but i tried not modify HTML too much and make code more universal.

[jsFiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/WGHUn/)